# Aws - do users pay for requests that returns Not Found status code?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-documentdb

Do users pay for requests that returns NOT FOUND in AWS DocumentDB? If no, from AWS's perspective, why? (AWS pricing page list prices per IO rate. Not sure if this would be considered a valid IO)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A request that returns NOT_FOUND is valid IO. You are still making a request (the I in IO), and you are getting a response (the O in IO), even if it’s a negative response.

——

The only cases I can think of where you *might* not be charged for a request would be if a connection times out while waiting for a response, or similar sort of error—but that is entirely my own speculation.